# Error on Uploading Program to ESP8266 via Foca v2.2 (USB to TTL Adapter)

Tags: esp8266

### BACKGROUND

To test the capability of uploading program to ESP8266,  I use an empty program with only a blank setup function and a blank loop function. The result showed me that there are a **espcomm_sync error** and a **espcomm_open error**. Any idea to solve this problem?

---

### HARDWARE

### [image: Foca v2.2] [image: ESP8266]

---

### PIN CONNECTION

```
  Foca v2.2 <-> ESP8266
        TXD <-> RXD
        RXD <-> TXD
        DTR <-> RST

Arduino UNO <-> ESP8266
        GND <-> GND
       3.3V <-> Vcc
```

---

### PIN DIAGRAMS

Foca v2.2
[image]

ESP8266
[image]

---

### ON LINUX UBUNTU 15.04

[image]

---

### ON WINDOWS 10

[image]

### REFERENCE

---

Bring IoT to Arduino, together [Getting Started] - http://www.arduinesp.com/getting-started

Comment: `Failed to open COM4` there is your first problem to look into.

Comment: Select the correct port. It'll probably work much better then.

Comment: Now the `Failed to open COM4` have been solved by changing the USB port. Now I got the same result in both windows and ubuntu...I have tried several things but no one works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nead to connect pin marked ch_pd on your esp module to vcc and also pin gp100 to ground to enable flashing mode. Once flashing is complete reboot without gp100 connect to ground and all should be fine.They use quiet a bit of current so you might nead an external power for the esp module as your ttl converter wont supply enough current.

**Connection**

```
Foca v2.2 <-> ESP8266
        TXD <-> RXD
        RXD <-> TXD
        DTR <-> RST

Arduino UNO <-> ESP8266
        GND <-> GND
       3.3V <-> Vcc
       3.3V <-> CH_PD
        GND <-> GPIO0
```

**Result**

[image]

visit http://www.esp8266basic.com/flashing-instructions.htm